# wpdb query comment and comment meta as one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am trying build a notification page where a author can go to see all the activity on their posts.

I am trying to get the comments made on all the authors posts - which i have working, but i also need to fetch two comment meta keys, one being "scientific_name" and the other being "common_name"

This works in fetching comment data like the comment author, title, content. But excludes the vital comment meta

```
 $suggestions = $wpdb->get_results( "
  SELECT $wpdb->posts.guid, 
  $wpdb->posts.post_title, 
  $wpdb->posts.ID, 
  $wpdb->comments.comment_author, 
  $wpdb->comments.comment_author_email,
  $wpdb->comments.comment_date, 
  $wpdb->comments.comment_content 
  FROM $wpdb->posts left join $wpdb->comments
  ON $wpdb->posts.ID=$wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID
  WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_author=".$current_user->id." 
  AND $wpdb->posts.post_status='publish' AND 
  $wpdb->comments.comment_type='comment' 
  OR $wpdb->comments.comment_type='suggestion'
");
```

I also have tried the following but is returning very wrong data:

```
$suggestions = $wpdb->get_results( "
  SELECT * 
  FROM $wpdb->posts as a left join $wpdb->comments as b 
  ON b.comment_post_ID = a.ID left join $wpdb->commentmeta as c 
  ON c.comment_id = b.comment_ID 
  WHERE a.post_author='63' 
  AND a.post_status='publish' and b.comment_type='comment' 
  OR b.comment_type='suggestion'
");
```

after much work i have what you see below, but there are so many loops.

```
$auth_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_author = '".$current_user->id."' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status='publish' AND $wpdb->posts.post_type='species'");
foreach($auth_posts as $auth_post) {
    $comments = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID = ".$auth_post->ID." AND $wpdb->comments.comment_type='comment' OR $wpdb->comments.comment_type='suggestion'");
    if($comments) {
        foreach($comments as $comment) {
            $comment_meta = get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID);
            echo $auth_post->post_title.'<br>';
            echo $comment->comment_author."<br>";
           // print_r($comment_meta['scientific_name']);
            echo $comment_meta['scientific_name'][0].'<br>';
            echo $comment_meta['common_name'][0].'<br>';

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Did you solve it?

Comment: Im trying to write a query which get all the author posts, then gets the comment and comment meta, but i am trying to do so without so many nested loops and queries